# Can't Install hmatrix on my Ubuntu Linux machine

Tags: haskell, matrix, cabal

I am trying to install hmatrix on my Ubuntu Linux machine (don't know if this is necessary, but it may help) and no matter what I do it will not work.

I run cabal install hmatrix and get this:

```
   Configuring hmatrix-0.13.1.0...
   Checking foreign libraries... FAIL
   *** Sorry, I can't link GSL.
   *** Please make sure that the appropriate -dev packages are installed.
   *** You can also specify the required libraries using
   *** cabal install hmatrix --configure-option=link:lib1,lib2,lib3,etc.
   setup: Package hmatrix-0.13.1.0 can't be built on this system.
   cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
   hmatrix-0.13.1.0 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
   ExitFailure 1
```

Apparently the ExitFailure 1 thing is a leftover from the original program.

When I run cabal configure I get

```
  Warning: 'hs-source-dirs: lib' directory does not exist.
  Checking foreign libraries... FAIL
  *** Sorry, I can't link GSL.
  *** Please make sure that the appropriate -dev packages are installed.
  *** You can also specify the required libraries using
  *** cabal install hmatrix --configure-option=link:lib1,lib2,lib3,etc.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated and thank you for reading.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to install the C libraries, something like `libgsl-dev` (or `-devel`), and `libgsl` itself, but that should be pulled in by the `dev` package. `hmatrix` is a binding to a C library, so you need that installed to be able to install `hmatrix`.

On my box, `ghc-pkg describe hmatrix` lists

```
extra-libraries: gsl lapack gslcblas
```

I'm not sure all of them are actually required for building `hmatrix`, but it wouldn't harm to also install the `dev` packages for `lapack` and BLAS (which may be something else than `gslcblas` on Ubuntu).

Answer (score 5):

On Ubuntu some of the required libraries can be loaded with   `apt-get command`. Try this,

```
sudo apt-get install libblas-dev libatlas-dev liblapack-dev
```

Comment: It seems the Ubuntu packages required are now:

    sudo apt-get install libgsl0-dev liblapack-dev

Answer (score 0):

Referring to [this file](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hmatrix-0.15.2.0/src/INSTALL.md) installation on Ubuntu is done using:

```
sudo apt-get install libgsl0-dev liblapack-dev
cabal install hmatrix
```