# Cabal install error hmatrix-0.15.2.1 on OSX 10.10 Yosemite + GHC 7.8 Cabal-1.22

Tags: haskell, cabal

I'm trying to install hmatrix-0.15.2.1 on OSX 10.10 Yosemite with GHC 7.8.3 and Cabal 1.22. The log gives this error message about the failure:

```
Checking foreign libraries... FAIL
   *** Sorry, I can't link GSL.
   *** Please make sure that the appropriate -dev packages are installed.
   *** You can also specify the required libraries using
   *** cabal install hmatrix --configure-option=link:lib1,lib2,lib3,etc.
```

What dependencies are required?

Answer (score 1):

I referenced this question [Can't Install hmatrix on my Ubuntu Linux machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9541500/cant-install-hmatrix-on-my-ubuntu-linux-machine) for clues on required dependencies.

You can get GSL for OSX via `brew install gsl`

Other libraries you may potentially need from brew:

```
brew install liblas
brew install lapack
```